# Compare IP's using Boost aiso

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

We have two ip addresses.

http://localhost/
http://127.0.0.1/

( both returns same host )

How to check for that using boost asio?

Comment: Do an ip::tcp::resolver::query and compare all the resolved addresses.

Comment: @sehe This is somehow out of my knowledge, could you consider Example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.asio-network-programming and the samples here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html show how to do it (mostly asynchronous, but that's not required)